# Rails API not updating records

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, api

I'm building a API using rails and my update method is acting odd.

I am using curl to update the users and when I look in the rails server terminal it seems as if it has updated them but when I look for the user in rails console he hasn't changed.

Same if I try to curl a single user record. It will only change if I curl for a update 3 times.

Here is my update method:

```
def update
  respond_with User.find_by(params[:uid]).update(user_params)
end

private

def user_params
  params.require(:user).permit(:username, :uid, :provider, :image_url, :full_name, :colour)
end
```

The curl command I am using is as followed

```
curl -v -H "Accept: application/json" -H "Content-type: application/json" -X PUT -d '{"username":"Bradley Jamil"}'  http://localhost:3000/api/v1/users/81888
```

And this is the output from the terminal 
[image: terminal output]

The user in question does not change until I run that same curl request another 2 times.

Also here is what my user model looks like

```
    # User Class
    class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      has_many :friendships
      has_many :friends, through: :friendships
      has_many :inverse_friendships, class_name: 'Friendship', foreign_key: 'friend_id'
      has_many :inverse_friends, through: :inverse_friendships, source: :user

      validates :provider, :uid, :username, :image_url, :full_name, :colour, presence: true
      validates :uid, uniqueness: true
      validates :provider, format: /\A(twitter)\Z/
    end
```

Comment: post your curl commands and rails logs. and please watch your grammar and post clearness.

Comment: Don't you want `update_attributes` rather than `update` ?

Comment: I also tried using `update_attributes` instead of `update` and the result was the same.

Comment: Separate the problem out a little more. Grab the user, see the current state of the user `puts user.inspect`, do your update, do another `puts user.inspect` and see if the attribute changed. This will all be output onto the terminal.

Comment: Do you have CSRF protection turned on?

Comment: Possibly you should use `params[:id]` instead of `params[:uid]`? According to the terminal output, input parameters use "id" and not "uid"...

Comment: Tried using `user.inspect`and the params looked as they should, the terminal commited them by still had not changed in the DB. Using params[:id] works first time but not what I was after... Looks like Im just going to have to use that. Thanks all.

Comment: This log is _not_ consistent with an update.  All that's there is `SELECT` sql.  For updates, you should see an `UPDATE` or perhaps `INSERT`.  Almost certainly a validation is failing. We'd have to see your `User` model to make sense of what is going on.

Comment: Updated with my users model

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like the comments suggest, I think there is a validation issue, and I'm not entirely sure you are calling save.

I would do something like this at least for debugging.

```
  def update
    respond_with User.find_by(params[:uid]).assign_attributes(user_params).save!
  end
```

Here we are doing a bulk attribute update (in memory), then flushing it to the DB with `save!`
As you probably know, `save!` will return `true` or raise an exception on failure.

The log will show the exception, and curl will get a 400 or 500 level error depending on how much rails magic there is on catching validation errors and returning a proper response code.